# Imputer on some columns in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imputation

I am trying to use `Imputer` on a single column called "Age" to replace missing values. But, I get the error: "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:"

Following is my code

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

dataset = pd.read_csv("titanic_train.csv")

dataset.drop('Cabin', axis=1, inplace=True)
x = dataset.drop('Survived', axis=1)
y = dataset['Survived']

imputer = Imputer(missing_values="nan", strategy="mean", axis=1)
imputer = imputer.fit(x['Age'])
x['Age'] = imputer.transform(x['Age'])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Imputer is expecting a 2-dimensional array as input, even if one of those dimensions is of length 1. This can be achieved using [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean')
imputer.fit(x['Age'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
x['Age'] = imputer.transform(x['Age'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

That said, if you are not doing anything more complicated than filling in missing values with the mean, you might find it easier to skip the Imputer altogether and just use Pandas [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) instead:

```
x['Age'].fillna(x['Age'].mean(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks - the `fillna` was a nice suggestion, too

Comment: Solved the problem.Thank you for your help and also for the alternate method.

Answer (score 3):

Although @thesilkworkm beat me in the curb, it may be useful to know why exactly your own code doesn't work.

So, apart from the reshape issue, there are two more mistakes in your code; the first is that you erroneously ask for `axis=1` in your imputer, while you should ask for `axis=0` (which is the default value, and that's why it works when omitted completely, as in @thesilkworkm'a answer); from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html):

> **axis** : integer, optional (default=0)
>
> The axis along which to impute.
>
> - If axis=0, then impute along columns.
> - If axis=1, then impute along rows.

The second mistake is your `missing_values` argument, which should be `'NaN'`, and not `'nan'`; from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) again:

> **missing_values** : integer or “NaN”, optional (default=”NaN”)
>
> The placeholder for the missing values. All occurrences of missing_values will be imputed. For missing values encoded as np.nan,
>   use the string value “NaN”.

So, just for offering an alternative but equivalent solution (beyond the one already provided by @thesilkworm), you can also fit & transform in one line:

```python
imp = Imputer(missing_values ="NaN",strategy = "mean",axis = 0)
x['Age'] = imp.fit_transform(x['Age'].reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are fit tranforming it use reshape(-1,1). Because method is expecting a 2D array as input but you are giving 1D array.

Ex: x['Age']=imputer.transform(x['Age'].reshape(-1,1))